# error PropTypes must be placed after render ...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

All I can say is: WHAT?

How this error is asking me to put PropTypes after the render method ?

Look at the error

```
src/components/ChatForm/index.js
   7:3   error  PropTypes must be placed after render                       react/sort-comp
  44:16  error  'onAddMessage' is missing in props validation for ChatForm  react/prop-types
```

**first PropTypes in the line 7**

```
  static PropTypes = {
    'onAddMessage' : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
```

I put `.func` because `onAddMessage` is a function...

**then in the line 44**

```
  _addMessage () {
    this.props.onAddMessage(input.value); // LINE 44
  }
```

**UPDATE**

ESLint config

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",          // https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint
  "plugins": [
    "react"                          // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react
  ],
  "env": {                           // http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-environments
    "browser": true,                 // browser global variables
    "node": true                     // Node.js global variables and Node.js-specific rules
  },
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "arrowFunctions": true,
    "blockBindings": true,
    "classes": true,
    "defaultParams": true,
    "destructuring": true,
    "forOf": true,
    "generators": false,
    "modules": true,
    "objectLiteralComputedProperties": true,
    "objectLiteralDuplicateProperties": false,
    "objectLiteralShorthandMethods": true,
    "objectLiteralShorthandProperties": true,
    "spread": true,
    "superInFunctions": true,
    "templateStrings": true,
    "jsx": true
  },
  "rules": {
/**
 * Strict mode
 */
    // babel inserts "use strict"; for us
    "strict": [2, "never"],          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/strict

/**
 * ES6
 */
    "no-var": 2,                     // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var
    "prefer-const": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const

/**
 * Variables
 */
    "no-shadow": 2,                  // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow
    "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2, // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow-restricted-names
    "no-unused-vars": [2, {          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars
      "vars": "local",
      "args": "after-used"
    }],
    "no-use-before-define": 2,       // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define

/**
 * Possible errors
 */
    "comma-dangle": [2, "always-multiline"],    // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle
    "no-cond-assign": [2, "always"], // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign
    "no-console": 1,                 // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console
    "no-debugger": 1,                // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-debugger
    "no-alert": 1,                   // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-alert
    "no-constant-condition": 1,      // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition
    "no-dupe-keys": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-dupe-keys
    "no-duplicate-case": 2,          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-duplicate-case
    "no-empty": 2,                   // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty
    "no-ex-assign": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-ex-assign
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 0,      // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-boolean-cast
    "no-extra-semi": 2,              // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-semi
    "no-func-assign": 2,             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-func-assign
    "no-inner-declarations": 2,      // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inner-declarations
    "no-invalid-regexp": 2,          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-invalid-regexp
    "no-irregular-whitespace": 2,    // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-irregular-whitespace
    "no-obj-calls": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-obj-calls
    "no-sparse-arrays": 2,           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sparse-arrays
    "no-unreachable": 2,             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable
    "use-isnan": 2,                  // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/use-isnan
    "block-scoped-var": 2,           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/block-scoped-var

/**
 * Best practices
 */
    "consistent-return": 2,          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return
    "curly": [2, "multi-line"],      // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/curly
    "default-case": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/default-case
    "dot-notation": [2, {            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation
      "allowKeywords": true
    }],
    "eqeqeq": 2,                     // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq
    "guard-for-in": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in
    "no-caller": 2,                  // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-caller
    "no-else-return": 2,             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-else-return
    "no-eq-null": 2,                 // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-eq-null
    "no-eval": 2,                    // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-eval
    "no-extend-native": 2,           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extend-native
    "no-extra-bind": 2,              // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-bind
    "no-fallthrough": 2,             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-fallthrough
    "no-floating-decimal": 2,        // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-floating-decimal
    "no-implied-eval": 2,            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implied-eval
    "no-lone-blocks": 2,             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-lone-blocks
    "no-loop-func": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func
    "no-multi-str": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-str
    "no-native-reassign": 2,         // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-native-reassign
    "no-new": 2,                     // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new
    "no-new-func": 2,                // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new-func
    "no-new-wrappers": 2,            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new-wrappers
    "no-octal": 2,                   // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-octal
    "no-octal-escape": 2,            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-octal-escape
    "no-param-reassign": 2,          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign
    "no-proto": 2,                   // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-proto
    "no-redeclare": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare
    "no-return-assign": 2,           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign
    "no-script-url": 2,              // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-script-url
    "no-self-compare": 2,            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-self-compare
    "no-sequences": 2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sequences
    "no-throw-literal": 2,           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-throw-literal
    "no-with": 2,                    // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-with
    "radix": 2,                      // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/radix
    "vars-on-top": 2,                // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/vars-on-top
    "wrap-iife": [2, "any"],         // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/wrap-iife
    "yoda": 2,                       // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/yoda

/**
 * Style
 */
    "indent": [2, 2],                // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent
    "brace-style": [2,               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style
      "1tbs", {
      "allowSingleLine": true
    }],
    "quotes": [
      2, "single", "avoid-escape"    // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes
    ],
    "camelcase": [2, {               // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase
      "properties": "never"
    }],
    "comma-spacing": [2, {           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-spacing
      "before": false,
      "after": true
    }],
    "comma-style": [2, "last"],      // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-style
    "eol-last": 2,                   // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/eol-last
    "func-names": 1,                 // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names
    "key-spacing": [2, {             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/key-spacing
        "align": "colon",
        "beforeColon": true,
        "afterColon": true
    }],
    "new-cap": [2, {                 // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap
      "newIsCap": true
    }],
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, { // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines
      "max": 2
    }],
    "no-nested-ternary": 2,          // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary
    "no-new-object": 2,              // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new-object
    "no-spaced-func": 2,             // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-spaced-func
    "no-trailing-spaces": 2,         // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-trailing-spaces
    "no-extra-parens": [2, "functions"], // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-parens
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,       // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle
    "one-var": [2, "never"],         // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/one-var
    "padded-blocks": [2, "never"],   // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks
    "semi": [2, "always"],           // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi
    "semi-spacing": [2, {            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi-spacing
      "before": false,
      "after": true
    }],
    "space-after-keywords": 2,       // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-after-keywords
    "space-before-blocks": 2,        // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-blocks
    "space-before-function-paren": [2, "always"], // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren
    "space-infix-ops": 2,            // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops
    "space-return-throw-case": 2,    // http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-return-throw-case
    "spaced-comment": [2, "always",  {// http://eslint.org/docs/rules/spaced-comment
      "exceptions": ["-", "+"],
      "markers": ["=", "!"]           // space here to support sprockets directives
    }],

/**
 * JSX style
 */
    "react/display-name": 0,         // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 2,    // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-boolean-value.md
    "react/jsx-quotes": [2, "double"], // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-quotes.md
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 2,         // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-undef.md
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,       // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-sort-props.md
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,  // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-sort-prop-types.md
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,       // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-react.md
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,        // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": [2, "allow-in-func"], // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 2, // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-update-set-state.md
    "react/no-multi-comp": 0,        // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-multi-comp.md
    "react/no-unknown-property": 2,  // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md
    "react/prop-types": 2,           // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 2,   // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md
    "react/self-closing-comp": 2,    // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/self-closing-comp.md
    "react/wrap-multilines": 2,      // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/wrap-multilines.md
    "react/sort-comp": [2, {         // https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/sort-comp.md
      "order": [
        "displayName",
        "propTypes",
        "contextTypes",
        "childContextTypes",
        "mixins",
        "statics",
        "defaultProps",
        "constructor",
        "getDefaultProps",
        "getInitialState",
        "getChildContext",
        "componentWillMount",
        "componentDidMount",
        "componentWillReceiveProps",
        "shouldComponentUpdate",
        "componentWillUpdate",
        "componentDidUpdate",
        "componentWillUnmount",
        "/^on.+$/",
        "/^get.+$/",
        "/^render.+$/",
        "render"
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is your eslint config?

Comment: @zerkms see my update

Comment: What if you put `everything-else` right before `render` in `order`? I think the capitalisation for `PropTypes` matters.

Comment: I would report an issue to the plugin then. There is a chance they don't support a class-based syntax (at least not a single trace of it in their docs)

Comment: @zerkms yes, please. Thank you.

Comment: ... I mean - I would if I was affected by the problem :-)

Comment: @zerkms yes, I just [did it](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/275), thanks :)